# How to get access to ioctl()

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get access to the ioctl() function from within Swift. It doesn't seem to be exported via the Darwin package.

I tried importing  in the Swift -Cocoa-Bridging-Header.h, but that doesn't seem to make it available either.

Any ideas? ;-)

Comment: you might not access to it in _Swift_.

Answer (score 5):

ioctl()/fcntl() are not automagically mapped to Swift because they use varargs. The fix is to write small wrapper functions, like:

```
int my_ioctlVip(int fildes, unsigned long request, int *val) {
  return ioctl(fildes, request, val);
}
```

Comment: Are you supposed to put that wrapper function in an objective-c framework and import the framework? That seems to work with Xcode but is there an option for Linux?

Comment: In Xcode you can use the same framework and put the wrapper in the bridging header, as shown in [SwiftSockets](https://github.com/AlwaysRightInstitute/SwiftSockets/blob/master/SwiftSockets/UnixBridge.c) etc. On Linux you would put it in a C library and create a system module for that. Having said that, the latest Linux Swift snapshot [seems to support varargs funcs](https://github.com/AlwaysRightInstitute/SwiftSockets/issues/20). Depending on the platform, you can also hack via [dlsym](https://github.com/AlwaysRightInstitute/SwiftSockets/blob/feature/linux/SwiftSockets/UnixUtils.swift)